# how can I make a text view visible only if a specific spinner item is selected

Tags: android, spinner

I have a custom dialog that has a spinner and some textfields, I'm trying to make one of the textfields only visible if a specific spinner item is selected , how can i do it please?

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">
   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#FF4081"
        />
   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:entries="@array/services"/>
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editcoutservice"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:backgroundTint="#FF4081"
        android:hint="Cout" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editstationservice"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:backgroundTint="#FF4081"
        android:hint="Station" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/marqueService"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:backgroundTint="#FF4081"
        android:hint="Marque" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/kilometrage_service"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:backgroundTint="#FF4081"
        android:hint="kilometrage" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonannulerconsommation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="annuler"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:text="ajouter"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/buttonenregistrerconsommation"
        android:textStyle="bold"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </Button>
  </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>`
```

and since i'm using a dialog in each fab this is what i've done : i know that i've made a mistake in the dialog because i didn't know how to close it, i'm new to this and i'm working on this app for school

```
mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            fabState = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
    fab.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (fabState==0){
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_consommation);
                dialog.setTitle("Ajouter Consommation");


                dialog.show();


                            }

              else if(fabState ==1 ){
                Toast toast2=  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"msg2                        done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

                toast2.show();


                                   }

            else if(fabState==2){
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_rappel);
                dialog.setTitle("Ajouter Rappel");
                dialog.show();

                                 }
            else{}

        }
    });
   }
```

Comment: Please post the code that you tried along with the issues with it.

Comment: done , i know i still didn't put the spinner in the main_activity , simply because i was thinking i will do it once i know how to do all the things i need ,  I hope you answer me soon thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement `OnItemSelectedListener` for your `Spinner`.

Like so:

```
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    final EditText kilometrageServiceEditText = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.kilometrage_service);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (position == 5) {
                kilometrageServiceEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                kilometrageServiceEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            kilometrageServiceEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Please, ensure you are checking `position` variable for correct value.

Comment: okay thank you but can you answer my question  on how can i make some of the textfields visible only if a specific item of spinner is selected? thanks

Comment: can you PLEASE take a look at my xml code you'll see the textview of kilometrage  , i want to make that one visible only if the position of the spinner is at 5 , can you please edit the code for me? to do this? so i can understand, i'm new to this please help me and thank you so much

Comment: what code do you want me to add ? strings.xml?  or something else?

Comment: @NefissaKhedher No do not add anything. I have modified code in answer. Now, it will show/hide kilometrage EditText.

Comment: by the way i wanted to ask i've been trying to put the code you sent me inside the (fabstate== 3) but it wouldln't work ? i mean is it okay if i put it outside of it i mean since its a dialog that shows once u cick on a fab inside a tab?